# How to only execute something every 30 frames

Tags: actionscript-3

My question is this, I want to add a rock every second (30 frames per second), I have different levels, this means I have different amounts of rocks in each level and I have different amount of speeds, so I want to add 10 rocks in a total of 30 seconds in level 1
in level 2 it's 20 rocks in a total of 20 seconds etc. I'm open to completly changing it, I just want the best solution. I want it to be dynamic so I can make a lot of levels. How should I got about doing this

I don't want to keep a counter and every time it's at 30 then add a rock and reset it.

Thank you in advance

```
switch(difficulty)
            {
                case 1:
                    timer = 30;
                    numberOfRocks = 10;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    timer = 20;
                    numberOfRocks = 20;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    timer = 10;
                    numberOfRocks = 30;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    timer = 5;
                    numberOfRocks = 40;
                    break;
            }

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop)
        }
        private function loop(e:Event):void
        {   
            for (var i:int = 0; i < (timer * 30); i++)
            {
                    a_bitmap = new a_class();
                    a_bitmap.x = 750;
                    a_bitmap.y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (600 - a_bitmap.height));
                    a_bitmap.height = 35;
                    a_bitmap.width = 35;
                    addChild(a_bitmap);
                    a_bitmap.name = "astroid" + i + "";
                    myArray.push(true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "I don't want to keep a counter and every time it's at 30 then add a rock and reset it." -- Why the heck not??

Comment: you can use this [`setInterval` or `setTimeout`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setInterval%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

A Timer may work better for you're needs than a frame handler.  I'd recommend using math to calculate your level parameters instead of hard-coded switch statements, then you can add as many levels as you'd like (or have your game go indefinitely)

```
var rockLoadTimer:Timer;

function gameInit():void {
    //your games initialization code here

    //create a timer that fires every second when running
    rockLoadTimer = new Timer(1000);

    //the function to call every time the timer fires.  You could also listen for TIMER_COMPLETE is wanted to run a function once all rocks are loaded
    rockLoadTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addNextRock);
}

function startLevel(difficulty:int = 1):void {
    //your code here to clear the level 


    //repeat count is used as the amount of rocks to load this level - level number times 10
    rockLoadTimer.repeatCount = difficulty * 10;

    //the delay time is how quickly you want the rocks to load.  this is 5 seconds divided by the difficulty level
    //so the first level would be every 5 seconds, second would be every 2 and a half seconds, third level would be every second and two thirds. etc.  
    rockLoadTimer.delay = Math.round(5000 / difficulty);

    rockLoadTimer.reset();
    rockLoadTimer.start();

}

function addNextRock(e:Event = null):void {
    //your rock creation code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Timer`, and create an instance of `a_class` during each tick:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 30); // One per second for 30 seconds
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addAsteroid);
timer.start();
function addAsteroid():void {
    a_bitmap = new a_class();
    // etc.
}
```

The timer delay is "asteroids per millisecond", so if you want to create 10 over 30 seconds you would set it to `30000/10` = 3000.

However, this approach works best when there is a smooth framerate- it will execute once per second, but the number of frames of animation can vary if Flash is running at less than 30fps. If your game works how I think it does, this could result in asteroids being "bunched up". So, **keeping a counter might be the better solution here,** unless you plan on handling the rest of your game logic (i.e. asteroid movement speed) in a way that can account for variations in frame rate.

If you want to use a counter:

```
var creationCounter:Number = 0; // put this at class level

// Then in the ENTER_FRAME event:
creationCounter += asteroids_per_second / 30; 
while (creationCounter-- >= 1) {
    a_bitmap = new a_class();
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: What value should I use for creationCounter? and I suppose 1 would be a good value for astroid_per_second?

Comment: `creationCounter` should be a class-level variable so that its value remains between calls, and it should start at 0. And `asteroids_per_second` would be 1 if you want an asteroid every 30 frames, or higher if you want to increase the difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use flash.utils.setInterval function .

```
setInterval(trace , 1000 , "trace message once per second");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `TweenLite`, you can use the `delayedCall` function, it can use time or frames,

```
// delayedCall(delay:Number, onComplete:Function, onCompleteParams:Array = null, useFrames:Boolean = false):TweenMax
TweenLite.delayedCall(30, addAstroid, null, true);
```

More info, see the docs: [http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/TweenMax.html#delayedCall()](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/TweenMax.html#delayedCall%28%29)